# Why doesn't my method execute when I call it from within the ImageUrl attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have an ASP.NET application and I would like to have a different logo depending on the environment (production, quality, etc...) so in my Site.Master page I have an image like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo_<%= EnvironmentHelper.GetRunningEnvironment() %>.png" AlternateText="logo"/>
```

The code behind is this:

```
    public static class EnvironmentHelper
{ public static string GetRunningEnvironment()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunningEnvironment"]) 
            ? "dev"
            : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunningEnvironment"];
    }}
```

I have added in the Site.Master page, the namespace so the method can be called:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Business.Helpers" %>
```

In the Web.config file, I created a variable in appSettings section like this:

```
<add key="RunningEnvironment" value="dev"/>
```

I have several images in my images folder with all the environments (logo_prod.png, logo_dev.png, etc....)

The problem is that the logo doesn't get displayed and the url of the picture is:

```
http://localhost/myapp/Images/logo_%3C%25=%20EnvironmentHelper.GetRunningEnvironment()%20%25%3E.png
```

why does the GetRunningEnvironment method is not evaluated ?

Comment: Try changing `<%= EnvironmentHelper.GetRunningEnvironment() %>` to `<%# EnvironmentHelper.GetRunningEnvironment() %>`.

Comment: Same thing with a # instead of =, no display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not allowed to use server tags inside that field.

You can simply fix this by either setting the URL from your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/logo_" + EnvironmentHelper.GetRunningEnvironment() + ".png";
}
```

or by using an HTML `img` element directly:

```
<img src="<%= "~/Images/logo_" + EnvironmentHelper.GetRunningEnvironment() + ".png" %>" alt="logo" />
```